# Index a DataFrame with a list and return NaN for out-of-bounds indices in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Normally when I index a DataFrame (or a Series) with a list of integer indices, I get back a subset of the rows, unless some of my indices are out of bounds, in which case I get an `IndexError`:

```
s = pd.Series(range(4))
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3

s.iloc[[1,3]]
1    1
3    3

s.iloc[[1,3,5]]
IndexError
```

But I'd like to get back a DataFrame (or Series) having an index identical to the list I queried with (i.e., parallel to the query list), with (the rows corresponding to) any out-of-bounds indices filled in with `NaN` :

```
s.something[[1,3,5]]
1    1
3    3
5    NaN
```

I don't think `join` tricks work because those want to operate on the DataFrame index (or columns).  As far as I can tell there's not even an "`iget`" integer-based `get` method if I wanted to manually loop over the indices myself.  That leaves something like:

```
indices = [1,3,5]
pd.Series([s.iloc[i] if 0 <= i < len(s) else np.nan for i in indices], index=indices)
```

Is that the best Pandas 0.18 can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @EdChum for inspiration, the general solution is:

```
s.reset_index(drop=True).reindex([1,3,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html#pandas.Series.reindex) to achieve this:

```
In [119]:
s.reindex([1,3,5])

Out[119]:
1     1
3     3
5   NaN
dtype: float64
```

This will use the passed index and return existing values or `NaN`

Comment: Ah, nice.  That works if the index is already consecutive integers, but we can achieve that with a `reset_index`.  I'll write up the full answer for posterity.  Thanks!